# Restart ffmpeg process streaming rtmp video if it fails using shell script

Tags: ubuntu, shell, shell-scripting, ffmpeg, rtmp

We use ffmpeg to forward streams live. Often due to unknown reasons or due to the stream stopping temporarily the command stops running in the background.

What's the best way to monitor and continue to retry the ffmpeg command in an infinite loop.

This is the command currently:

```
avconv -i rtmp://example.com:1935/rtplive/Live2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s hd720 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 30  -bufsize 600k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://example.com/live/adfaf" > avconv.log  2>&1 &
```